Standard deviation of the norm of the random vector
Let's say I have $n$ iid random variables $v_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,c)$ with $c$ is a constant, and put them into a vector: $V=\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\\
...\\
v_n
\end{bmatrix}$. I am interested in the norm of $V$, $||V||$. Is it a random variable? If so, what is the mean and standard deviation of it?
Thank you for your help!

It would depend on the norm, I assume. For the usual 2-norm and standard normal $v_i$, you'd get a Chi-distributed random variable.

Yes, I am interested in the 2-norm. I checked the Chi-distribution and found something unintuitive. It looks like stacking random variables that are zero mean will result in a vector whose norm is not zero mean. Why is this the case?

The coordinates are squared before being added together, the result is non-negative. If a non-negative random variable has expectation zero, then it is almost surely zero.

I think that you are looking for this guy. Yours is central so $\mu_i = 0$, with $\sigma_i = c$.

Hi @EmanYalpsid, I checked the noncentral chi distribution you suggested but it seems that this distribution is for $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}  (\frac{v_i}{\sqrt{c}})^2)} $ but what I am interested is actually $\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{n} v_i^2} $. Is there a way to convert between these two?

One is a constant times the other: $\sqrt{c} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}  (\frac{v_i}{\sqrt{c}})^2)} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} v_i^2}$, so the expected value (and standard deviation) of the two are related nicely.
